# How to Release File-Lock on File Created by Shell in VBA?

Tags: vba, shell, file-access, filelock

This command generates an output file:

**Update: See new command**

```
Shell "cmd /c fc file1 file2 > result.txt"
```

i initially didn't use `cmd /c` at the front of the command:

```
Shell "fc file1 file2 > result.txt"
```

That failed to generated the expected result.txt file. i don't know why. Including `cmd /c` at the front of the command makes it work.

The subsequent `Open` statement gets "Path/File access error"

```
iFile = FreeFile
Open "result.txt" For Input As iFile
```

Neither the file nor parent directory are open in Windows Explorer.

The following changes don't help (`TaskKill` and `AccessRead`):

```
vPID = Shell("cmd /c fc file1 file2 > result.txt", vbHide)
Shell "TaskKill /F /PID " & CStr(vPID), vbHide
iFile = FreeFile
Open "result.txt" For Input Access Read As iFile
```

The `Open` statement works if it's run as a separate, subsequent process.

How to do the `Open` in the same process?

Comment: Maybe it's a timing problem? Can you access it vie `open` after waiting a second or more?

Comment: @UnhandledException Even if i step thru the code slowly, i still get "Path/File access error".